# pythonの正規表現がうまくできない

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

下記のような3つの文字列から期待値通りの結果を得るpythonの正規表現を教えてください。

```py
text1 = "こんにちは (こんばんは) (Hello (Hello))" // 期待値："Hello (Hello)"
text2 = "こんにちは(こんばんは) (Hello(Hello))" // 期待値："Hello(Hello)"
text3 = "こんにちは こんばんは (こんにちは こんばんは)" // 期待値："こんにちは こんばんは"
```

Comment: まず自分で試してみて, 問題点が出たら **どのポイントが** 分からないかを尋ねると良いでしょう

Comment: 自然言語（日本語）でよいので、行ないたいマッチングのルールを説明してみて下さい。既に回答も出ていますが、説明が無いと質問者さんの意図と一致しているのか判断できません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[regex · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) を利用する場合。

```py
import regex as re

text1 = "こんにちは (こんばんは) (Hello (Hello))" # 期待値："Hello (Hello)"
text2 = "こんにちは(こんばんは) (Hello(Hello))"   # 期待値："Hello(Hello)"
text3 = "こんにちは こんばんは (こんにちは こんばんは)" # 期待値："こんにちは こんばんは"
rx = r'(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)'

for text in (text1, text2, text3):
    m = re.findall(rx, text)
    if m: print(m[-1][1:-1])

# Hello (Hello)
# Hello(Hello)
# こんにちは こんばんは
```